# Comparing Original Array of Dom Elements with Sort Array of Dom Elements and check if they are different

Tags: html, jquery, dom-traversal

I have a structure of dynamic DOM elements that I'm continuously evaluating with a for loop and a setInterval. While in that interval I sort the array and then change the dom with a JQuery Sort function in order to order my DOM structure on the fly.

The thing is I only want to change the DOM if the sort function is actually changing the order of elements (usually this happens when a new DOM element comes into the structure dynamically), if the sort function runs again over an already sortered array I don't want to do anything with the dom.

I have found A LOT of ways to compare if Arrays are equal but my case is special since i don't really care about the arrays elements / content but I really need to check if those elements are not in the same order so i can change the dom.

```
    setInterval(function () {       
    //Incoming Chat Structure Variables
    var $incomingChatsTable, $incomingChatsRows, $incomingChatTags
    $incomingChatsTable= $("div[__jx__id*='incoming_list__list_content_container']")
    $incomingChatsRowsContainer=$("div[__jx__id='___$_194__visitor_list__incoming_list__list__content']")
    $incomingChatsRows = $("div[class*='renderers_Incoming']")
    $incomingChatTags = $( "div[__jx__id*='incoming_list__list__content'] div[class*='renderers_Incoming'] .visitorlist_tags .jx_ui_html_span:last-child .tag").toArray()        
    $popupTrigger = $("div[jx\\:list\\:rowid]") 
    //Assigning Priorities Function
    function assignPriority(arrayParent) {
        for ( var i=0; i <= arrayParent.length; i++) {
            var actualRow = $(arrayParent[i])
            var minutesInQueue = $(actualRow).find('.time_cell').text().substr(0,2)
            var priorityVal = parseInt(minutesInQueue)
            var actualRowTags = $( actualRow ).find('.tag').toArray()
            $(actualRow).addClass('priorityRow')               
            for (var k=0; k <= actualRowTags.length; k++) {
                let normalHolderTag = $(actualRowTags[k]).text().toLowerCase()
                if (normalHolderTag === 'vip') {
                    priorityVal += 30
                    $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)                    
                } else if ( normalHolderTag === 'rg' ) {
                    priorityVal += 20
                    $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)
                } else if ( normalHolderTag === 'accountclosure' ) {
                    priorityVal += 10
                    $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)                    
                } else {
                    $(actualRow).attr('data-priority', priorityVal)   
                } 
                //$(actualRow).find('.numbers_cell').text(priorityVal)
            }
        }     
    }   
    //Sorting Incoming Chats By Priority
    function orderByPriority(container) {
        myArray = container.find('.priorityRow')
        var changed = false
        myArray.sort(function(a,b){
            contentA = parseInt( $(a).data('priority') )
            contentB = parseInt( $(b).data('priority') )
            if ( (contentB - contentA) * ( myArray.indexOf(b) - myArray.indexOf(a) ) > 0 ){
                changed = true
            }                     
            return (contentB - contentA)                             
        })
        if(changed) {
            $(sortedArray).prependTo( container )
        } else{
            console.log('No need To Sort')
        }
    }
    setInterval(function () {
        assignPriority( $incomingChatsRows )
        orderByPriority( $incomingChatsRowsContainer )
    }, 500)
}, 1000)
```

**UPDATE:**

myArray is now a global variable, I have added an IF statement evaluating the sort function result and multiplying that result by the a, b indexes. If that's greater than 0 then i change the value of my "changed" variable to "true" BUT I'm getting a "**myArray.indexOf is not a function**" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a line of code in your `orderByPriority` sort function which sets a variable to true only if it actually changes something:

```
function orderByPriority(container) {
        var myArray = container.find('.priorityRow')
        var changed = false
        myArray.sort(function(a,b){
            contentA = parseInt( $(a).data('priority') )
            contentB = parseInt( $(b).data('priority') )
            if((contentB - contentA)*(myArray.index(b)-myArray.index(a))>0){ 
            //check if these have the same sign, i.e. something has changed
            changed = true;
            }
            return (contentB - contentA)                              
        })
        if(changed){}//do something to modify DOM
    }
```

The sort function has three possible outputs which will determine whether the two inputs need to be sorted:

- Greater than 0: sort a to an index greater than b
- Less than 0: sort b to an index greater than a
- Equal to 0: don't change the order

The possible conditions which will result in a change being made are therefore:

- Output greater than 0 and the index of a is currently less than the index of b
- Output less than 0 and the index of a is currently greater than the index of b

We can represent the difference between the two indexes as `index(b)-index(a)`. If the index of a is currently less than the index of b, this value will be positive. Otherwise, the value will be negative.
We can thus see that the above conditions are *really* saying:

- if output and `index(b)-index(a)` have the same sign, something needs to be changed.

We can check if they have the same sign by multiplying them by eachother and testing if the result is greater than 0. This means that something has changed, so inside the `if` condition we set `changed` to `true`

Comment: thanks @Leaf the Legend. I'm getting a "myArray.indexOf is not a function" error, do you know what's going on ?. Trying to grasp the logic of your answer too, can you develop a little bit your if statement ? Many Thanks !

Comment: Hi @Lowtrux, I've edited my answer to explain the logic behind the if statement. Hopefully it makes sense now. As to why indexOf is not a function, the only reason I could think of is that `myArray` is not defined within the sort function. I think the problem is that the sort function technically has a different scope to the `orderByPriority` function, so the `var` declaration doesn't extend to it. To fix this, you could make `myArray` a global variable, either by removing the `var` keyword or declaring it outside your function. Hope this works!

Comment: thanks SO MUCH for your explanation. I have tried to make myArray a global variable by removing the "var" keyword by is still giving me the same error "myArray.indexOf is not a function". Any other idea why ? and again Thanks a lot !

Comment: That's weird. You could have a look at the documentation on [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), which might help you troubleshoot. Otherwise I would try standard troubleshooting practises such as `console.log(myArray)` and see if it's really an array of the form you were expecting. Maybe also try explicitly declaring `var myArray;` outside the function? Removing the `var` keyword should have done the trick though. If it really just doesn't work out, I'm sure there are other ways of doing what you need to do. Good luck!

Comment: @Lowtrux I just realised that myArray isn't actually an array. I had a closer look through your code and realised it's actually a jQuery object! Sorry, my bad. I'm not an expert in jQuery, but I'm fairly sure if you just replace all the `indexOf`s with `index`, it should work. See the index documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/index/#:~:text=as%20an%20argument%2C%20.-,index()%20returns%20an%20integer%20indicating%20the%20position%20of%20the,index()%20will%20return%20%2D1.)

Comment: Thanks @LeaftheLegend Does "myArray = container.find('.priorityRow').toArray()" will solve the problem ?

Comment: Actually it does but I have checked that changed is always false so the dom never gets changed.

Comment: Did you try just using `index` instead of `indexOf`? (Without the toArray part)

Comment: That actually Work. Thank you SO MUCH !

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help

Comment: I'm noticing that the script is buggy as soon as new elements came into the myArray structure. I'm wondering if it have to do with the need of some sort of setTimeout for the whole script. Just want to be sure that I'm getting the right behavior from the conditional statement that makes the dom change. I'm wondering if the whole DOM structure of "myArray = container.find('.priorityRow')" is being refreshed everytime a new element is added since it seems like the sorting method is not including some elements. Hope you can shine a light again and many thanks !

Comment: @Lead the Legend any thoughts ? I would really like to refact the code in order to make it work 100%. Will really appreciate your advice.